# Problema con Angular 2 y CROS

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, spring-boot, http-post

Buenas tardes comapñeros,

Tengo un problema con Angular2 y ciertas peticiones de tipo POST al realizarlas desde el cliente de la aplicación.

Escenario:

- La API está implementada en **SpringBoot**.
- Aplicación cliente **Angular 2+** HttpClient.
- **Están en diferentes dominios (CROS)**.

La peticion desde Angular es similar a la siguiente:

```js
let userAccessToken = 'Bearer ' + this.storage.retrieve('UserAccessToken');  
let other = this.storage.retrieve('other');      

const headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8;')
    .set('Authorization', userAccessToken)
    .set('Other', other);

this.http.post( "https://api.xxxxx.yyyy/", {}, { headers })
.subscribe(
    (val) => {
        console.log("POST call successful value returned in body", val);
    },
    response => {
        console.log("[ERROR] => POST call in error => ", response);
        console.log("[ERROR] => HEADERS => STATUS => ", response.headers.get('status'));
    },
    () => {
        console.log("The POST observable is now completed.");
    }
);
```

Obtengo una respuesta de del servidor de tipo **200 OPTIONS** la cual contiene **Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ***

```
  Access-Control-Allow-Headers : authorization, content-type
  Access-Control-Allow-Methods : GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS    
  Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *
  Access-Control-Expose-Headers : xsrf-token
  Access-Control-Max-Age    : 3600
  Content-Length    : 0
  Date : Tue, 23 Jan 2018 15:18:52 GMT
  Vary : Origin
```

Con esta respuesta intuyo que el backend está configurado correctamente, sin embargo **NO puedo realziar la peticion POST ¿Por qué puede ser?**

Mucahs gracias.

Comment: Problema en el servidor Spring-boot

Answer (score 1):

**[Solución]**

Al existir cabeceras personalziados **custom-headers**, se deben habilitar explicitamente en la configuración CROS de la **API Spring-boot**

A modo orientativo en la configuración de **Spring-boot** se debe agregar algo como:

```
// prepare cors config
CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();

// Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
corsConfig.addAllowedOrigin("*");

// Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
corsConfig.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
corsConfig.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.POST);
corsConfig.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);
corsConfig.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.DELETE);
corsConfig.addAllowedMethod(HttpMethod.OPTIONS);

// Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
corsConfig.setMaxAge(3600L);

// Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization, content-type, xsrf-token
corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("authorization");
corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("content-type");
corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("custom-header");
corsConfig.addAllowedHeader("other");
```

Un saludo